# Sorting Elements using Queue in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

I am trying to sort elements(Integers) present in queue, using another queue.
Queue does not have negative numbers or duplicate values
Queue must sorted in ascending order.(head -> tail)
sample input:4
[7 3 9 5]

output: [3 5 7 9]

```
import java.util.*;

public class Source {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = s.nextInt();
    while (n-- > 0)
        queue.add(s.nextInt());
    sort(queue);
}

// Method to sort the queue
static void sort(Queue<Integer> queue) {
    Queue<Integer> queue2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    queue2.add(queue.remove());
    while(queue.size()!=0){
    int temp = queue.remove();
   queue2.add(temp);
    while(temp<queue2.peek()){
        queue2.add(queue2.remove());
    }
    }
    System.out.println(queue2);
}
```

}

Comment: Have you checked out this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397674/java-sorting-a-queue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Sorting a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397674/java-sorting-a-queue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no negative numbers in the queue I was thinking doing as follows: 
 
1. insert a negative number to the first queue (the "dummy" technique).
 
2. Search for the minimum number in the first queue until you hit the dummy.
 
3. Remove the dummy.
 
4. Search in the queue for the minimum value that you found in step 2, remove it and insert it to the second queue. 
5. Follow these 4 steps until the first queue is empty.

Java code:

```
static void sort(Queue<Integer> q1) {
    Queue<Integer> q2 = new Queue<Integer>();
    int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while (!q1.isEmpty())
    {
        q1.insert(-1);
        while(q1.head() != -1)
        {
            if (q1.head() < min)
            {
                min=q1.head();
            }
            q1.insert(q1.remove());

        }
        q1.remove(); //removing the -1
        while (q1.head() != min)
        {
            q1.insert(q1.remove());
        }
        min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        q2.insert(q1.remove()); //inserting the minimum to the second queue.
    }
    System.out.println(q2);
}
```