# Ordering a queue with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, queue

I want to print the arrays in a queue but in ascending, numerical order.

For instance, queue contains

```
{3, 5},
{4, 5}, 
{0, 4}, 
{3, 4}, 
{4, 6}
```

How would I make it print as follows?

```
{0, 4}, 
{3, 4}, 
{3, 5}, 
{4, 5}, 
{4, 6}
```

I also checked, but I can't seem to find a way to push an array back into the queue from like the front?

I would appreciate any tips or help.

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work:

```java
while (queue.size() > 0) {
  int[] current = queue.remove();
  int[] current1 = queue.peek();
  
  if (queue.size()!=0) {
    if (current[0]>current1[0]) {
      int[] holdarr = current;
      current = queue.remove();
      queue.add(holdarr);
    } else if (current[0] == current1[0] & current[1]>current1[1]) {
      int[] holdarr = current;
      current = queue.remove();
      queue.add(holdarr);
    }
  }
  
  System.out.println(current[0] + ", " + current[1]);
```

Comment: What type is `queue`?

Comment: For sorting, you need to implement (or use) a [sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm). All sort algorithms take longer than linear time (on average). If your queue does not support random access, it will be best to just consume the entire queue and put the contents in an array or List that you can sort efficiently.

Comment: Hint: Your algorithm prints the first element if it is smaller than the second one, but what if the third would be even smaller?

Comment: oh i see! in the end, i decided to just put everything into a matrix to sort but i was just wondering if i could sort it since my values were already in a queue... thanks tho! @Hulk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Sorting a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397674/java-sorting-a-queue)

Comment: ahh i saw that people mainly use PriorityQueue i think? and it seems like it's mainly for integers or i may be wrong... but i'll try it out! thanks! @Hulk

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a = {
        {3, 5},
        {4, 5},
        {0, 4},
        {3, 4},
        {4, 6}};
    Queue<int[]> que = new ArrayDeque<>();
    for (int[] e : a)
        que.add(e);

    que.stream()
        .sorted(Arrays::compare)
        .forEach(e -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e)));
}
```

output:

```
[0, 4]
[3, 4]
[3, 5]
[4, 5]
[4, 6]
```

Comment: ooo i'll try it out! thankss!!